# "Natural" ways of interpolating unitary matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-theory, interpolation

Given two unitary matrices $A$ and $B$, that are "near" each other in some sense (perhaps $\left\lVert A-B\right\rVert <\epsilon$ for some norm, what are some sensible ways to interpolate between them in the space of unitary matrices?

That is, I am looking for functions $C=f(A,B,t)$ such that $C$ is unitary, $A=f(A,B,0)$ and $B=f(A,B,1)$, and for $0<t<1$, $\left\lVert A-C\right\rVert <\epsilon$ and $\left\lVert B-C\right\rVert<\epsilon$.

Comment: If $||AB^{-1} - 1 || < 1$ (which occurs if $\epsilon < 1$ and we are using a C*-algebra norm), then we can write $AB^{-1} = \exp (2\pi i D)$ where $ 0 \leq D \leq I$ (in the usual partial ordering on C*-algebras). Hence $g:t \mapsto \exp (2\pi i t D)$ is a path of unitaries joining the identity to $AB^{-1}$, never straying very much from the identity. Then $t\mapsto g(t) B$ is a path of unitaries that is within $\epsilon$ of $A$ and $B$, is $B$ at zero, and $A$ at $1$; is this what you want?

Comment: Homotopies of unitaries are well studied in C*-algebraic K-theory.

Comment: matrices, e.g. the orthogonal factor of a matrix decomposition such as the polar or the qr decomposition.

Comment: The geodesic from A to B wrt to the metric induced by the Frobenius norm is given by $f(A,B,t)=Aexp (tlog (A^{-1}B)) $ where exp resp. log is the matrix eponential resp. logarithm. If log and exp are too expensive you could use $P ((1-t)A+tB)$ where P is a projection onto unitary matrices, e.g by taking the unitary factor of the polar or the qr decomposition